# loading jQuery via modernizr

Tags: jquery, modernizr

Just starting a new HTML5 project and using modernizr.js

I noticed on the modernizr docs page it says you can use the following:

```
Modernizr.load([
  {
    load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js',
    complete: function () {
      if ( !window.jQuery ) {
            Modernizr.load('js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js');
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

So in my HTML I have this:

```
<script src="scripts/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>
<script>
Modernizr.load([
    {
        load: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js',
        complete: function () {
            if ( !window.jQuery ) {
                        Modernizr.load('scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js');
            }
        }
    }
]);
</script>
```

But looking at firebug, no jquery is loading.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Cheers,
Adi

Comment: You should avoid this, you're killing parallel script downloading and making page loads slower (with noticeable flicker when jq starts applying its styles).

Comment: On the site it says 'Modernizr.load does not slow anything down, and can sometimes offer a small boost in performance by loading scripts asynchronously and in parallel.'?

Comment: How do you figure, the browser starts loading everything it sees in the `<head>` tag, and your script won't be there *until after modernizr finishes downloading and the script executes*.

Comment: @Blindy, your logic is all off.  `<script>` tags cannot be downloaded in parallel, so at WORST this takes just as long as sticking them both in as `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Adi, where are you checking in Firebug?  I mean, are you simply adding a `console.log` command somewhere, or are you looking at the window properties?

Comment: @Blindy: you're incorrect here. At the worst, it's same-as. Modernizr is supposed to be the first thing run anyways, so whether you load jQuery via a script tag or through Modernizr, it'll hit virtually at the same time. Modernizr.load is just an alias for yepnope, which claims that it loads scripts asynchronously and non-blocking. I haven't verified that claim myself, but if it's true, that would actually give the Modernizr approach a bump as the script tag for jQuery definitely would be synchronous and blocking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modernizr is a small lib and it gets loaded and executed quickly and yes, it will load scripts in parallel, so good idea to use it. About your error, remove the https: from the url and try as in the example.

Comment: Hi ToyDaVirus. Turns out the issue was the development version doesnt use the loader. At top in the comments was '* Modernizr has an optional (not included) conditional resource loader called Modernizr.load(), based on Yepnope.js (yepnopejs.com). To get a build that includes Modernizr.load(), as well as choosing which tests to include, go to www.modernizr.com/download/' So just download from there and all is fine :)

Comment: oh! Cool. so didn't build your custom version and download. Anyways, way to go!

Answer (score 1):

As i had the same problem and Adi worked it out here is the reason why Modernizer.load won't work for some people:

> Hi ToyDaVirus. Turns out the issue was the development version doesnt use the loader. At top in the comments was '* Modernizr has an optional (not included) conditional resource loader called Modernizr.load(), based on Yepnope.js (yepnopejs.com). To get a build that includes Modernizr.load(), as well as choosing which tests to include, go to www.modernizr.com/download/' So just download from there and all is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Put below code before

```
Modernizr.load([
                {
                    test: Modernizr.mq('(min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 728px)'),
                    yep : ['mob.css', 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css', 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js'],
                    nope : 'pc.css'
                }
            ]);
```

this way you can load multiple files such as css, js